# Could not find proper message validator for message type 'json', please define a capable message validator for this message type

Tags: citrus-framework

I've encountered an unusual problem while conducting integration tests using Citrus. During multiple runs of the same test, I'm consistently encountering an error that looks something like this:

```
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Could not find proper message validator for message type 'json', please define a capable message validator for this message type
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:227)
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.doExecute(TestCase.java:152)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
    at com.consol.citrus.Citrus.run(Citrus.java:403)
    at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.invokeTestMethod(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:131)
    at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.run(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:108)
    at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.run(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

This issue seems to occur intermittently and I'm uncertain about the root cause. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with Citrus integration tests? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot or mitigate this recurring error would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

p.s: I'm using tests in XML format,JDK 1.8 and Citrus 2.8.0.